# connecting two objects

Tags: modeling, node-editor

so i wanted to connect two objects in this case its a plane connected to the bottom of a head mesh, i create a plane, line it up delete a edge on the head mesh and plane and i select both vertices in edit mode and i fill them the problem is that it shows up black while the middle is simply extruding the mesh. actually im not sure why it shows up as black?, but im trying to achieve the same results as if i was extruding the mesh. shouldnt the uv map of the head be making it atleast the same color[image]

Comment: i joined them than filled them i think it has to do with the uv map im not sure why it turns black

Answer (score 0):

Pressing "CTRL-J" in object mode should join the two objects, and make them the same color. It works in my case.